# transposing a named range in a VBA range object

Tags: vba

I have a named range "CompletedSheetYears" which is a one column table in my DataTables sheet. The years are sorted vertically in chronological order from top to bottom, newest year at top.

This causes a problem in my charts as when I grab the range of years to use in the range of dates for the chart, it plots backwards. Yes, I know I can transpose the axis in the chart but that moves not only the dates to the right order but it moves the scale to the right of the chart which I don't want.

I know I can loop in reverse to create the right range but there must be a simpler way to do it, my VBA is rusty not having used it for some time now.

Is there a simpler way? i.e.

```
Set rangeReverseDates = Range("CompletedSheetYears").Transpose
```

or something to that effect. (Obviously, there is no Transpose method for range, or none intellisense showed me)

Comment: What type of chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

`Range("d1").Resize(1, Range("TTT").Cells.Count) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("TTT"))`

Comment: Transpose generally takes vertical to horizontal and vice versa, at least when doing it manually in a sheet. This code A. needs a Set and B. doesnt work for me when attempted